# Localization of sheaves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Let $(X,\mathscr{O}_X)$ a ringed space and $\mathscr{F}$ an $\mathscr{O}_X$-module. Let $U\subseteq X$ be an open subset, and suppose we have $\mathscr{F}|_U=\mathscr{O}_U$, then for $x\in U$, how does this imply $\mathscr{F}_x=\mathscr{O}_{X,x}$? The explanation I saw was "because localization preserves exactness", but I don't quite understand how does it work here. Can somebody explain?

Comment: Isn't it just that the stalk of a sheaf is equal to the stalk of that sheaf restricted to any open set, so that $\mathscr{F}_x = (\mathscr{F}|_U)_x = \mathscr{O}_{U,x} = \mathscr{O}_{X,x}$?

Comment: @NateGallup that looks like an answer to me!

Comment: Could you provide a link to the original source where you saw this 
'proof sketch' that your claim follows from the fact that 'localization 
preserves exactness'. You see here are couple of proofs given but no one 
uses it explicitely. That's why 
I'm curious how it can be alternatively proved using this property of localizations.

Comment: It's from the lecture video from my school. My professor didn't provide any other details besides mentioning "because localization preserves exactness"......

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Turning my comment into an answer:**

This is essentially the same as the other two excellent answers, but is more elementary (if, for example, you don't want to think about the inverse image sheaf, cofinal systems, etc.). For any sheaf $\mathscr{G}$ on a topological space $X$ and any open set $U \subseteq X$ with $x \in U$, the stalk of the restricted sheaf $(\mathscr{G}|_U)_x$ is equal to the stalk of the original sheaf $\mathscr{G}_x$. In your case, you can simply apply this twice:
$$
\mathscr{F}_x = (\mathscr{F}|_U)_x = \mathscr{O}_{U , x} = \mathscr{O}_{X , x}
$$

Comment: Just a quick comment: Of course the simplicity here hides the fact that $\mathscr{F}_x = (\mathscr{F}|_U)_x$ essentially comes from a colimit argument as in some of the other answers.

Comment: @QiZhu: +1 Yeah, for sure the colimit argument is the best one! The other two answers are super elegant and general! I only added my answer because this isomorphism can also be understood without using colimits if, as was the case for me when I first learned this stuff, one is not comfortable with category theory/colimits.

Comment: I actually think that yours is the best! :) The comment only meant that you implicitly used the other answer (but theorems are proven to be used).

Comment: by the way: one facet of the problem I still haven't solved/understood.
The OP remarked that the explanation which was given in the original source
is that 'because localization preserves exactness'. That is an exact
sequence stays under localization exact. Does anybody see how concretely *this* 
observation provides also an answer of OP's question?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know how an argument that explicitely exploits the fact that
'localization preserves exactness'
works, but instead I would like to use the property of injective limits
with resprect to cofinal index systems. It says that if
$\varinjlim_{i \in I} A_i$ and $J \subset I$ is a *cofinal* system then
$\varinjlim_{i \in I} A_i= \varinjlim_{j \in J} A_i$.
recall that by definition $F_x= \varinjlim_{x \in V} F(V)$ where we consider
the injective system consisting of open $V \subset X$ containing
$x$. Then the subsystem of $V' $ with $V' \subset U$ is a cofinal system and
therefore

$$F_x= \varinjlim_{x \in V} F(V)= \varinjlim_{x \in V \subset U} F(V)  
\varinjlim_{x \in V \subset U} O(V)=   \varinjlim_{x \in V } O(V)=
O_{X,x} $$

But don't accept it as 'answer' so far, instead as an 'alternative' argument,
since I'm also curious how the proof of your problem using
that 'localization preserves exactness' in detail work, I don't know it.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how much formality you have seen but for me the most satisfying proof is:

let $j: U \rightarrow X$ be the inclusion and $i: \{\star \} \rightarrow U$ of image $x$. We have pullback functors $$j^{-1}: Sh(X) \rightarrow Sh(U) \\ i^{-1}: Sh(U) \rightarrow Sh(\{\star\}) \\
(j \circ i)^{-1}: Sh(X) \rightarrow Sh(\{\star\}).$$
And they are compatible with composition: $i^{-1} \circ j^{-1} = (j \circ i)^{-1}$.

By definition $\mathcal{F} \vert_U = j^{-1} \mathcal{F}$ and $O_U = j^{-1}O_X$.
Hence $\mathcal{F}_x = (j \circ i)^{-1} \mathcal{F} = i^{-1} \circ j^{-1} \mathcal{F} = i^{-1} \circ j^{-1} O_X = (j \circ i)^{-1} O_X = O_{X,x}$